# ls inside bash script didn't found just created file

Tags: bash, java

bash script contains like:

```
./java_application
ls logs/app.log
```

java_application deletes and creates new log file: app.log

when I run this bash script I receive:

```
ls: logs/app.log  No such file or directory
```

Is workaround exists?

Comment: are you sure that the java app creates the log in that subdir? that it doesn't do a `cd`, or open the log someplace else?

Comment: yes, sure. when i change name on app.log.test that is not re-created ls succeceds